# eu queria fazer uma query que me retornasse o seguinte dados no mongodb

Tags: query, modelagem, mongodb

COLECTION JOGOS

```
{
  id : 10,
  casa : "Sport",
  visitante : "Chapecoense",
  horario : "2017-07-20 11:00:00"
}
```

COLLECTION APOSTADOR

```
{
  nome : "wedson",
  apostas : [
   {
     idjogo : 10,
     opcao : 1,
     valores : 1
   }
  ]
}
```

eu queria fazer uma query que me retornasse o seguinte

```
{
  nome : "wedson",
  apostas : [
   {
     idjogo : 10,
     opcao : 1,
     valores : 1,
     id : 10,
     casa : "Sport",
     visitante : "Chapecoense",
     horario : "2017-07-20 11:00:00",
   }
  ]
}
```

no caso seria a tabela apostador com os dados completos dos jogos, nao queria cadastrar o apostar com todos os dados apenas com o id e depois tentar puxar tudo que preciso dessa forma, se eu estiver errado me corrijam, mas dando essa ideia de como puxar fico agradecido :)

Comment: Você está usando o mongo como banco relacional, o ideal não é usar assim. A melhor forma seria colocar todas as informações dentro de uma collection apenas (documento).